# How to echo a param out in PHP

Tags: php, image, variables, echo

So I have a class with all setParams

```
$this->setParams('matchwins', $users->getInfo($_SESSION['user']['id'], 'matchwins'));
```

So I could just use `{matchwins}` around my website)

I tried to do the following statement on my user homepage.

```
<?php
    $clan = $_GET["clan"];
    $file = 'http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/'. $clan .'/avatar.png';
    if (file_exists($file)) {echo "<img src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/'. $clan .'/avatar.png'/>";}
?>
```

I'm new to PHP, does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: did you tried this `"<img src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/$clan/avatar.png'/>";`

Answer (score 2):

You should be using double quotes to include your variable, the single quotes are being used to hold the `src` attribute of the `img` tag you are trying to echo.

```
echo "<img src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/" . $clan  . "/avatar.png'/>";
```

Comment: I tried,   `code` <?php
    $file = 'http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/'. $clan .'/avatar.png';
    if (file_exists($file)) {echo "<img src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/'. $clan .'/avatar.png'>";} 
   ?> `code`  it didnt work

Comment: @user3818791 if this answer doesn't solve your problem, you'll need to be more specific to where your problem is - this answer is sufficient to fix your syntax error.

Comment: That is not correct... you have basic syntax errors with the extra semicolons. The only thing wrong with your code is shown correctly in the answer.

Comment: @user3818791 you should also just use the `$file` variable. You've checked the file exists, great. Use it instead of re-writing the path. `if(file_exists($file)) echo '<img src="' . $file . '">';`

Comment: ** ` <?php
    $clan = "{clan}";
    $file = "<img src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/{" . $clan  . "}/avatar.png'/>";
    if (file_exists($file)) echo "<img src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/warfare/images/clans/" . $clan  . "/avatar.png'/>";
   ?> ` ** no luck.